# FadeOut Splash page/homepage fadeIn not working

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am new to jQuery. I am using [this code](http://chaosm.net/jquery/splash_dissolve.php), which works perfectly fine there with jQuery 1.3.2. When I use the same jQuery 1.3.2 in my project, it works fine too. But when I replace jQuery to version 1.10.2 it doesn't work. Why it doesn't work with jQuery 1.10.2? Is there a way to make it work? Excuse me if I am really unable to understand. Thank you in advanced for your help.

I am using the same jQuery code showed on [that page's source code](http://chaosm.net/jquery/splash_dissolve.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function(){
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#splash").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#content").show();
    });
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle for this animation and it works with jQuery 1.10.1 and 1.11.0.

How are you referencing jQuery 1.10.2? I have to think that is the problem, did you remove your reference to jQuery 1.3.2?

[Click here for demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/CxGxv/)

```
$(function(){
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#splash").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#content").show();
    });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @Sanpopo. I did remove my reference to jQuery 1.3.2 in my file's <head> but it didn't work either. But I took your advice and went to look up the JQuery documentation and I found the solution. I just had to reference the jQuery Migrate file in the <head> along with the new jQuery 1.11.0. According to the jQuery site, the jQuery Migrate plugin should always be used when transition from older versions of jQuery. Hope this solution will help anyone in the future.